# How to distinguish between different processes using the same name?

Tags: windows, powershell

So I am running several instances of my program and I have to be able to distinguish between the instances in a good way from powershell. Since every instance is installed in a separate folder I thought that i could use:

```
get-process -Name MyProgram* | Select-Object name, path
```

and get a list showing me the folder from which the process was started. Unfortunately this returns with the path empty.
So I tried a bunch of other properties that might be unique but all of them come back empty. 
What am I doing wrong? Or can I do something else perhaps?

I am using windows 8 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be running with elevated permissions to see the path information of processes you're not the owner of.

Comment: This would make sense! Unfortunately I just left the office so I can not try it until Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use PID? Or does your program start child-processes. `Path` works for me, like:

```
Get-Process iexplore | Select-Object ID, Name, Path

   Id Name     Path
   -- ----     ----
10792 iexplore C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
13928 iexplore C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
17144 iexplore C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
17772 iexplore C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
20896 iexplore C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

Does `ExecutablePath` or `CommandLine` return anything?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name LIKE 'iexplore%'" | Select-Object ProcessID, Name, ExecutablePath, Commandline

ProcessID Name         ExecutablePath                                        Commandline
--------- ----         --------------                                        -----------
    17144 iexplore.exe C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe       "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" ...
    32016 iexplore.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE...
    36744 iexplore.exe C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE       "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" ...
```

If the process doesn't belong to you, then you need to run it as admin/elevated.

Comment: I don't have the pid unfortunately.

Comment: You don't need to know the PID. You said you're looking for a way to separate the processes, and PID is one possible answer. PID is unique per process.

Comment: Yes. I can separate them. But how do I know which pid the one I want to kill has? I am looking for a particular instance.

Comment: That wasn't you question. You asked how to separate them from eachother. Are the window titles different? Did the second suggestion help?